# Unity3D - Вставка Prefab'a в Prefab

Tags: c#, unity3d

Возможно ли по средством кода добавить в Prefab другой Prefab? К примеру есть рукоядка топора и одеть на неё лезвие топора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Логика действий такая:

Вы вызываете метод. В этом методе есть ссылка и на префаб лезвия и на префаб рукоятки. С помощью метода Instantiate() вы создаёте на сцене копии этих префабов. Затем через transform.SetParent() у одной из них устанавливаете его чайлдом другой.

На абстрактном примере это выглядит так:

```
    public Handle _hanldePrefab;
    public Blade _bladePrefab;

    void CreateAxe()
    {
        var handle = Instantiate(_hanlderPrefab);
        var blade = Instantiate(_bladePrefab);
        blade.transform.SetParent(handle.transfrom);
    }
```

Надеюсь, объяснил понятно, если что - уточняйте.